# Check for (.csv or .dat) file extension among multiple files and if not send alert to the user

Tags: c#, ssis

I am new to SSIS,

Every 30 mins I will receive a single file or multiple files in the Source Directory

I need to loop through these files and check if it has a `.csv` or `.dat` extension:

- If it is not: send alert to the user.
- If it is: execute the package

**EDIT : I have tried;**

```
Main()
{ 
    try
    {
        string[] filenames;
        filenames = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:Input_Data\");
        string FileExtension = Path.GetExtension("filenames");
        if (FileExtension == ".DAT" && FileExtension == ".csv") 
            Dts.Variables["FileExist"].Value = 1;
    }
    catch 
    { 
        Dts.Variables["FileExist"].Value = 0; 
    }

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

But even if the file exist with `.dat` extension, it is returning 0 and sending the alert.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're here to help, not do your job for you, so prove that you've at least tried doing this yourself.

Comment: i have tried doing the following  with script task     public void Main(){ try{string[] filenames;filenames = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:Input_Data\");string FileExtension = Path.GetExtension("filenames") if (FileExtension == "*.DAT" && FileExtension == "*.csv") Dts.Variables["FileExist"].Value = 1;}}
            catch
            {
                Dts.Variables["FileExist"].Value = 0;
               }Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;},But even if the file exist with .dat extension,it is returning 0 and sending alert

Comment: if you're using && in the IF, you'll never pass....how could it be both values?

Comment: I changed  to  if (fileextension == ".DAT" | fileextension == ".csv"), its returning 0 still and sending alert

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the native Foreach Enumerator?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant to write...

```
if (FileExtension == ".DAT" || FileExtension == ".csv")
```

Otherwise it would never evaluate to true.

Also you probably want a loop of some kind, your current structure is trying to access all the files at once (and not even quite doing that)

```
filenames = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Input_Data\");
foreach(string filename in filenames)
{
    string FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
    if (FileExtension == ".DAT" || FileExtension == ".csv") 
        Dts.Variables["FileExist"].Value = 1;
}
```

Edit:

Based on what I think you are saying it sounds like you want FileExist to equal 1 only when it contains only DAT and CSV types and no other types, in that case you want to reverse the logic a bit.

```
filenames = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Input_Data\");
Dts.Variables["FileExist"].Value = 1;
foreach(string filename in filenames)
{
    string FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
    if (FileExtension != ".DAT" && FileExtension != ".csv") 
        Dts.Variables["FileExist"].Value = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried the following script,public void Main(){string[] filenames;filenames = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\MVNE\BTDB\data_staging\VOICE\UCA\Input_Data\");         
foreach (string filename in filenames){string FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename); if (FileExtension == ".DAT" || FileExtension == ".csv")  Dts.Variables["FileExist"].Value = 1;else  Dts.Variables["FileExist"].Value = 0;}}it execute the remaining task onlyifthereis.dator.csvfile,butitooneedtosendalerto theuserifthereisfileamongthemultiplefilethatisnotinthisformathowtodothatinC#,canwecalla vbscript from C#??

Comment: It is a lot easier to update your question with new information than cram it into a comment block like that, I can't really read any of that.

Comment: I have added 2 task,one for FileExist=1(execute pacakge) and another for FileExist=0(SendMail) but even if there is file of .txt format among the .DAT file,it is not sending alert but it goes to FileExist=1 and execute the remaining.How to do this.I need to send alert if there is any file other than .dat/.csv file

Comment: @user1521157 I edited my answer to address what I think you are trying to say, but in the future you should localize your problems and either open a new question based on them, or edit your existing question if the problems are very closely related.